# How to create Table or Funnel chart on visual force page using apex code?

Tags: apex, visualforce, dashboard

I want to create a Table chart or Funnel chart on my visual force page with the help of Apex.

I have created bar chart, Scatter chart, donuts chart on visualforce page all these working fine but I don't know how we can create Table or Funnel chart on visualforce page with the help of apex.

Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a Report using a report builder, add a required chart to a report and use that Report ID in visualforce page.

[analytics:reportChart](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm)

Use this component to add Salesforce report charts to a Visualforce page. You can filter chart data to show specific results. The component is available in API version 29.0 or later.

[image]

**Visualforce Page**:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" >
     <analytics:reportChart ReportId="00O28000008i9Z5" showRefreshButton="true" size="medium" cacheResults="false"  />
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: I have already mentioned in my question that I want to create these on the basis of apex, i don't want to create using  <analytics:reportChart >.